# Can rails scopes filter on the number of associated classes for a given field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, scope, mongoid

I am using Rails 3 with Mongoid.

I have a Folder class that can then be shared with other User classes as such

```
class Folder
  has_one :owner
  has_many :users
```

I am trying to create two scopes one that can be used to return all private folders, and one to return all shared folders. Is there any way to count the number of associations within a scope?

```
  scope :personal, where(:users.count => 0)    #Erroring on count...
  scope :shared, where(:users.count.gt => 0)  #Erroring on count...
```

I've considered building methods instead but would prefer scopes as I wish to chain them with other scopes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're accessing referenced documents - your `users` method is a virtual attribute, which you can't access during your query. You can however use `user_ids` (the array of `User` ids in your `Folder` document) to perform the kinds of queries you want:

Either of these should work for your personal scope:

```
scope :personal, where(:user_ids.size => 0)
# or
scope :personal, where(:user_ids => [])
```

And for your shared scope:

```
scope :shared, where(:user_ids.ne => [])
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, could you please give some light on me?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26911752/717506

Answer (score 4):

```
scope :personal, where({ "$or" => [{:user_ids => nil}, {:user_ids => {"$size"=>0}}] })
scope :shared, where({ "$nor" => [{:user_ids => nil}, {:user_ids => {"$size"=>0}}] })
```

This should handle both the cases when :user_ids is not set or is null and when it is set to an empty array.

Comment: The `$or` and `$nor` queries here are redundant. By default, Mongoid creates empty arrays for all new associations, so `user_ids` will never be `nil`.

Comment: On my local system I have a college, which has_many students, it does contains nil user_ids field, hence the solution.

Comment: @theTRON Just got an upvote so coming back, this can happen if association is added at a later stage when db already has some documents.