# How can I find records by "count" of association using rails and mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-many

With these models:

```
class Week
  has_many :proofs
end
class Proof
  belongs_to :week
end
```

I want to do something like:

```
Week.where(:proof.count.gt => 0)
```

To find only weeks that have multiple proofs.

There is one answer that seems to address this:

[Can rails scopes filter on the number of associated classes for a given field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515800/can-rails-scopes-filter-on-the-number-of-associated-classes-for-a-given-field/6520882#6520882)

But in this example, there is no such attribute as proof_ids in Week since the ids are stored with the proofs.  This does not work for example:

```
Week.where(:proof_ids.gt => 0)
```

How is this query possible?  Conceptually simple but I can't figure out how to do this with mongo or mongoid.

Similarly, I'd like to order by the number of proofs for example like:

```
Week.desc(:proofs.size)
```

But this also does not work.

I do realize that a counter-cache is an option to both my specific questions but I'd also like to be able to do the query.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With rails (and without counter_cache), you could do:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proofs

  def self.by_proofs_size
    sort_by { |week| week.proofs.size }
  end

  def self.with_at_least_n_proofs(n = 1)
    select { |week| week.proofs.size >= n }
  end
end
```

Even though each of those operations produces 2 queries, this is far from ideal.

The pair of queries is repeated (=> 4 queries for each operation) with scopes (bug?):

```
scope :with_at_least_n_proofs, -> (n = 1) { select { |w| w.proofs.size >= n } }
scope :by_proofs_size, -> { sort_by { |w| w.proofs.size } }
```

The ideal is probably to use counter_cache

```
scope :with_at_least_n_proofs, -> (n = 1) { where('proofs_count >= ?', n) }
scope :by_proofs_size, -> { order(proofs_count: :desc) }
```

Comment: You can remove includes(:proofs) to increase performance by a ton.  Currently, you're loading all of the data in :proofs, when all you really need is a quick count query.  Try it out.

Comment: it will kill you application because you will receive all weeks with all proofs from database to memory of your application

Comment: @antiqe That's why I mentioned using a counter_cache

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the best solution, as it maps it through a array, but this does the job: (the other solutions mentioned here gives me exceptions)

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :has_proofs, -> { any_in(:_id => includes(:proofs).select{ |w| w.proofs.size > 0 }.map{ |r| r.id }) }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I'm way off - but would you be able to use a simple counter_cache in the weeks table?  Then you could do something like week.proofs_count.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my question, I know a counter_cache is an option but I'd rather do a query if possible in this case.  If that isn't going to work, then I'll definitely do the counter cache.