# make_flaggable: Filter by total flaggings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a listing of models that users can look through and if they deem a particular item inappropriate they may flag it. I want to exclude items whose flaggings reach a certain threshold, but I'm unsure how to accomplish this since the flaggings count isn't a part of my model.

I know that I can use the following to get the count of flaggings for a model:

```
Model.flaggings.count
```

But how can I filter on that? I tried adding a scope in a way I thought might work to no avail:

```
def self.appropriate
  return unless self.flaggings.count > 5
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either

1) cache the flaggings count, and filter on it in Model.  This is a counter_cache and you can hook it up manually or let rails keep it straight for you.

2) add a scope to filter on the count.  This answer is related: [How can I find records by "count" of association using rails and mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223518/how-can-i-find-records-by-count-of-association-using-rails-and-mongoid).  This approach makes it tougher to add other scopes.

Persoanlly, I like to do this:

3) Cache all the ids of "inappropriate" Model items in another place (eg Memcache or Redis) and use this list of IDs to filter results in the scope.

```
Model.appropriate.where(...)
```

Where the 'appropriate' scope method would get the values from the cache.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.appropriate
    where('models.id not in', Model.inappropriate_ids)
  end

  def self.inappropriate_ids
    Rails.cache.fetch('appropriate_model_ids'){
      # Get all ids of appropriate items in a single array.
      # Something like this
      Flagging.having('count(*) > 5').count(:group => :model_id).keys 
    }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the having clause to accomplish this.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many: :flaggings

  def self.appropriate_items 
    select("models.*, count(flaggings.id")).joins(:flaggings)group("models.id, flaggings.model_id").having("count(flaggings.id) < 5")  
  end

end
```