# scope filter records depends on associations count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, scope, has-many

I used MongoDB, I have model `retailer` that had many `stores`, and I want to return retailers which has at least one store.

I found this question: [How can I find records by “count” of association using rails and mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223518/how-can-i-find-records-by-count-of-association-using-rails-and-mongoid)

But the accepted answer is:

```
scope :with_at_least_n_stores, -> { where('stores_count >= 1') }
```

Depends on `stores_count` field in retailer model, but I don't have this field.

Any solution to find retailer that has at least one store using scope without adding field as `stores_count` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```
scope :with_at_least_n_stores, -> { stores.size > 0 }
```

Comment: No, I tried it before, and got this error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'stores' for Retailer:Class`

Comment: Ok, see here the answer by Patrick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223518/how-can-i-find-records-by-count-of-association-using-rails-and-mongoid